# Get a weekly email containing all new content from a list of blogs

Tags: email, rss, blogging

I would like to receive a weekly email containing any new content from a list of blogs that I'm interested in.  I searched Google for "get weekly email updates from a list blogs", "program for emailing aggregated blog updates", and "program for aggregating blog updates and sending as an email."  I didn't find very much, and what info I did find seemed to be for bloggers, not blog readers.  I have tried a few feed readers, but I want to be able to receive the new content via weekly email, and I haven't been able get any feed readers to do this for me.  How can I accomplish this?  Is it possible or will I have to stick with some sort of feed reader?

Comment: You could always use something like FeedDemon to forward to a server you run, then have the server email you weekly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Windows, or a Windows emulator, you should try Awasu: http://www.awasu.com/. It can do exactly what you need "right out of the box".

1. Subscribe to your feeds
2. If needed, you can filter the content with saved keyword searches
3. Group certain feeds together in a Report
4. Schedule the report to run at a specific date/time or at a periodic interval
5. Set the report to be emailed to you or FTP'd to a server (or whatever, Awasu allows for custom post-report processing)

Awasu has a powerful templating engine, so you can customize the look of the individual feeds and/or the report.

Awasu does a lot more than this; too much to list here; we're just scratching the surface...

Online help: http://www.awasu.com/help/3.0/hh_start.htm

Awasu has been around for 11 years, is still being developed and supported and is designed for **super users**.

**Full disclosure:** I'm an Awasu super user, fan and addict. :-)